# C#, Swift, AND Android in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, swift, ide

I'm still a coding/C# newbie. I've spent the last 30 days learning C# probably about 8-12 hours per day. That said, I'm trying to get a setup where I can build Android apps, do some Swift programming, and continue learning C#.

I am currently running Visual Studio Express 2015 and it's for the Desktop platform, not Windows 10 apps.

My question is, can I use Visual Studio to do all of these things in one combined installation? I ask this because I was just about to install Xamarin and then I also found this Silver compiler which ALSO says it includes Visual Studio 2015: http://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/default.aspx .

However, I'm not sure if I were to install Xamarin and then try to install Silver, is the Silver's Visual Studio going to over-write the Xamarin or my original installation of the IDE? **I want to have ONE Visual Studio installation that allows me to start C#, Swift, AND Android projects.**

I am also slightly confused on the different variations of Visual Studio 2015. By having Express, do I already have Community or is this a different IDE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you get Visual Studio Community instead of Express since Express is very limited. In community you are able to do all of those.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift you only can use the language in the Xcode IDE. Swift can use in the Mac OS and Ubuntu, can not use in the windows now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct. Silver is a project where you can use swift to write native apps on Windows. Xamarin is a completely different thing. With this tool you can write platform-independent with C#. For Mac, Android, iOS, and nativly with C# on Windows. It should be your prepared way, if you want to write many code in C#.